# apply encodeuricomponent to all ajax calls in an application globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, encodeuricomponent

I have ajax calls like this at several places in my application.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: Json.stringify(Values),
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

For these ones, I would like to add encodeURIComponent to data sent as below:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: encodeURIComponent(Json.stringify(Values)),
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

Is there any way that I can do this globally without manually editing it everywhere?

Comment: jQuery parses whatever you pass as data, why would you URLencode it ?

Comment: It's not parsing correctly when I have a "+" sign in the data. "+" is being converted to space

Comment: A `+` is a space in an URL ?

Comment: sorry, I edited the post. I too have Json.stringify applied to my data. Not sure if it's Json.stringify replacing "+" with spaces or something else. But using encodeURIComponent, I am able to retain "+" in my data on the server side.

Comment: And why would you stringify, just pass the object to jQuery, and it handles the rest ?

Comment: I needed to do as I am using a Javascript serializer on my server side code, which requires JSON string.

Comment: I'm pretty sure jQuery will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own function for doing it.

```
var myAjax = function (options) {
  if (typeof options.data !== "undefined") {
    options.data = encodeURIComponent(options.data);
  }
  return $.ajax(options);
};
```

Then in your code replace:

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: url, data: Json.stringify(Values), dataType: 'json' });
```

With:

```
myAjax({ type: 'POST', url: url, data: Json.stringify(Values), dataType: 'json' });
```

Whatever you do, don't monkey patch!

Comment: Not sure how would I use this function in respect to my code?